# Enhanced for loop not executing

Tags: java, for-loop

**UPDATE: Please read the second part of this post that reads "UPDATE". I 've gotten some parts of the code to function since the original post. Thank you!**

I have an enhanced for loop in my toString method which returns a string:

```
public String toString() {
    for (SelectedItem item: cartItems) {
        return "Item: " + item.getItemNumber() + "\nQuantity: " + item.getQuantity + "\nUnit Price: $" + item.getUnitPrice + "\nTotal Price: $" + (item.getUnitPrice * item.getQuantity);
    }
        return "";
}
```

However, all my code returns is :

"[]

[]". I believe that my code is only executing the return "" part and not the "return 'Item: ...'" section. For reference, here is my full class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ShoppingCart implements Cart  {

private double total;
private double tax;
private double shipping;
private int totalQuantity = 0;
ArrayList<SelectedItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<SelectedItem>();

public ShoppingCart() {
}

public void addItem(SelectedItem newItem) {     
    for (SelectedItem item: cartItems) {
        if (newItem.getItemNumber() == item.getItemNumber()) {
            totalQuantity = newItem.getQuantity() + totalQuantity;
        } else {
            totalQuantity = newItem.getQuantity();
            cartItems.add(new SelectedItem(newItem.getItemNumber(), newItem.getDescription(), newItem.getUnitPrice(), newItem.getQuantity()));
        }

    }
}

public void deleteItem(int deleteItemNumber) {

}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public double getTax() {
    tax = total * 0.045;
    return tax;
}

public double getShipping() {
    if (total <= 10) {
        shipping = 2.50;
    } else {
        shipping = total * 0.15;
    }
    return shipping;
}

public String toString() {
    for (SelectedItem item: cartItems) {
        return "Item: " + item.getItemNumber() + "\nQuantity: " + item.getQuantity + "\nUnit Price: $" + item.getUnitPrice + "\nTotal Price: $" + (item.getUnitPrice * item.getQuantity);
    }
        return "";
}
```

}

and here is the **SelectedItem** class:

```
public class SelectedItem implements Item {

private int itemNumber;
private String description;
private double unitPrice;
private int quantity;

public SelectedItem(int itemNumber, String description,
        double unitPrice, int quantity) {
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    this.description = description;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getItemNumber() {
    return itemNumber;
}

public double getUnitPrice() {
    return unitPrice;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int newQuantity) {
    quantity = newQuantity;
}
```

}

Lastly, my tester class that is supposed to create instances of the SelectedItem Object:

```
public class CartTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ShoppingCart cart1 = new ShoppingCart();
    cart1.addItem(new SelectedItem(1, "widget", 0.95, 5));
    cart1.addItem(new SelectedItem(2, "gadget", 0.25, 10));
    cart1.addItem(new SelectedItem(3, "doohickey", 0.35, 3));
    cart1.deleteItem(2);
    cart1.addItem(new SelectedItem(3, "doohickey", 0.35, 2));
    cart1.addItem(new SelectedItem(4, "thingamabob", 0.12, 7));
    System.out.println(cart1.toString());

    ShoppingCart cart2 = new ShoppingCart();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        String nameString = "Volume " + i;
        cart2.addItem(new SelectedItem(i, nameString, 10.99, i));
    }
    System.out.println("**********");
    System.out.println(cart2.toString());
}
```

}

Please help me!! Here is the snippet of how the output is supposed to look:

```
Item: widget
Quantity: 5
Unit Price: $0.95
Total Price: $4.75
```

**UPDATE: I've gotten my code to print out the following:**

```
aItem: widget
Quantity: 5
Unit Price: $0.95
Total Price: $4.75

**********
Item: Volume 1
Quantity: 1
Unit Price: $10.99
Total Price: $10.99
```

.. But it still doesn't print out all the items in ShoppingCart. I've modified my ShoppingCart class and I think the problem is either the AddItem method or toString method. Here is my updated ShoppingCart class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ShoppingCart implements Cart  {

private double total;
private double tax;
private double shipping;
private int totalQuantity = 0;
ArrayList<SelectedItem> compareTo = new ArrayList<SelectedItem>();
ArrayList<SelectedItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<SelectedItem>();
String itemDescription = "";
int itemQuantity;
double itemUnitPrice;
double itemTotal;

public ShoppingCart() {

    }

public void addItem(SelectedItem newItem) { 
    boolean found = false;
    if (cartItems != null && !cartItems.isEmpty()) {
       for (SelectedItem item : cartItems) {
           if (newItem.getItemNumber() == item.getItemNumber()) {
               found = true;
               item.setQuantity(newItem.getQuantity() + item.getQuantity());
           } 
       }
    } else {

    }
    if (found) {

    } else {
        cartItems.add(new SelectedItem(newItem.getItemNumber(), newItem.getDescription(), newItem.getUnitPrice(), newItem.getQuantity()));
    }

}

public void deleteItem(int deleteItemNumber) {
    for (SelectedItem item: cartItems) {
        if (deleteItemNumber == item.getItemNumber()) {
            item.setQuantity(0);
        }
    }
}

public double getTotal() {
    for (SelectedItem item: cartItems) {
        total = item.getQuantity() * item.getUnitPrice();
    }
    return total;
}

public double getTax() {
    tax = total * 0.045;
    return tax;
}

public double getShipping() {
    if (total <= 10) {
        shipping = 2.50;
    } else {
        shipping = total * 0.15;
    }
    return shipping;
}

public String toString() {
        for (SelectedItem item: cartItems) {
            return ("Item: " + item.getDescription() + "\nQuantity: " + item.getQuantity() + "\nUnit Price: $" 
        + item.getUnitPrice() + "\nTotal Price: $" + (item.getQuantity()*item.getUnitPrice()) + "\n");
        }
            return "\nTotal: $" + getTotal() + "\nTax: $" + getTax() + "\nShipping: $" + getShipping() +
                    "\nGRAND TOTAL: $" + (getTotal() + getTax() + getShipping());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why return within for loop?

Comment: As @Steephen: states, a return in the loop makes it no longer behave as a loop. It's only doing what you code it to do.  You're not doing a critical debugging step -- you need to step through your code mentally to see what it is doing as it runs, including going through each loop in your mind. If you don't learn to do this, you will not understand the code or the bugs.

Comment: No, I understand that but I need a return statement after the for loop because it returns an error saying "This method must return a result of type String." And the method type is String so I need to return a string..

Comment: The problem is that your `addItem` function does not work. You are adding items to the list your are traversing (which would throw an exception if it would reach that point), but since the list initially is empty, it will skip the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments using a return statement is wrong unless you want to print out only the first item. So you should better do as follows:

1. add the following `toString()` method into `ShoppingCart`:

   ```
   public String toString() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (SelectedItem item : cartItems) {
           sb.append("Item: " + item.getDescription() + "\nQuantity: " + item.getQuantity() + "\nUnit Price: $" + item.getUnitPrice() + "\nTotal Price: $" + (item.getQuantity()*item.getUnitPrice()) + "\n\n");
       }
       return sb.toString();
   }
   ```
2. Lastly your `addItems` method should be changed as follows:

   ```
   public void addItem(SelectedItem newItem) {
       boolean found = false;
       if (cartItems != null && !cartItems.isEmpty()) {
          for (SelectedItem item : cartItems) {
              if (newItem.getItemNumber() == item.getItemNumber()) {
                  found = true;
              } 
          }
       } 
       if (found) {
           totalQuantity += newItem.getQuantity();
       } else {
           totalQuantity = newItem.getQuantity();
           cartItems.add(new SelectedItem(newItem.getItemNumber(), newItem.getDescription(),newItem.getUnitPrice(), newItem.getQuantity()));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the only class that I'm allowed to edit is the ShoppingCart class. Therefore, I am very restricted in editing my code. I have modified my code slightly using my own methods and your suggestion, and have gotten it to print out: Item: widget
Quantity: 5
Unit Price: $0.95
Total Price: $4.75

**********
Item: Volume 1
Quantity: 1
Unit Price: $10.99
Total Price: $10.99

But it still doesn't print out all the items in the shopping cart. I will post my updated ShoppingCart class since that is the only one that has been modified from the above post.

Comment: I modified the `toString()` method of `ShoppingCar` class. The `addItem()` method should be used as is. Try it out. You should also edit the class in the original question instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The issue was the return statement. Once I used System.out.println, it worked fine!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the `return` statement in the loop means only the first iteration will be executed and the rest will be skipped.